# airflow backfill dag not running until given end date

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have a backfill DAG, which is scheduled to run yearly from 01-01-2012 to 01-01-2018, but this runs only from 01-01-2012 until 01-01-2017. Why is this not running until 01-01-2018 and how to make it run until 2018.

Here is the code that I have used in the DAG:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2012,1,1),
    'end_date': datetime(2018,1,1),
    'email': ['sef12@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}

dag = DAG(
        dag_id='SAMPLE_LOAD',schedule_interval= '@yearly',default_args=default_args,catchup=True,max_active_runs=1, concurrency=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how Airflow handles scheduling. From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html):

Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be triggered soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Your run for 2018 will start once 2018 is over, since that's the end of the interval.